# TableView Scroll Is Interfering With Swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In one screen 80% of the view is a table. The table cells can be swiped for edit actions. That works well.

However, I added a swipe gesture to the mainView, which triggers a segue. Using that mainView gesture, if they swipe a location on the screen (a location that's not a cell) the segue gesture is recognized and they're brought to a new screen. That's good.

**My problem** is that if they swipe an empty table location perfectly it segues but if the swipe is imperfect (slightly up or down), the tableView scrolls instead. How can I solve this without disabling scrolling? This seems like a big problem because they have to swipe PERFECTLY horizontal and most users swipe carelessly.

[image]

Comment: You mean if in an empty area where the `UITableView` is not present, the user scrolls vertically, the `UITableView` scrolls? That shouldn't be the case. Check in your debug view heirarchy if that area is really empty?

Comment: @Rikh The UITableView is present. But it's empty (no cells).

Comment: You could try adding a `UIPanGesture` and comparing offset values to determine which direction user scrolled in, maybe that'll work!

Comment: You mean add a UIPanGesture to the UITableView then, when it's called, get the offsets and run the segue if it looks more like a swipe than a scroll? Not a bad idea! A little bit more code than I was hoping for. If I don't find an easier answer, I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: It just hit me, what you can also try is, instead of having a bottom constraint of your `UITableView` to the superview, you could give it a fixed height constraint which you will have to set to numberOfCells * cellHeight. This will ensure the `UITableView` is not in the area apart from cells and swipe gesture should work as expected!